# How to normalize encoding names, like ks_c_5601-1987 to CP949?

Tags: php, utf-8, mb-convert-encoding

I am fetching emails from a mail server and converting the message to UTF-8 charset and save it in DB.To convert the charset I am using mb_convert_encoding but it fails to convert  `gb2312` and `ks_c_5601-1987`. On googling I found that instead of `gb2312` I can use `CP936` and for `ks_c_5601-1987` use `CP949`.

Going by the above approach it would mean to maintain a separate list of charset mappings in my code. 
Is there a way to normalize names of encodings to names internally supported by PHP hence eliminating the need to maintain any map locally?

Comment: `iconv` recognizes `ks_c_5601-1987` but cannot convert. `mb_convert_encoding` doesn't support `949` or `ks_c_5601-1987` at all. `iconv` recognizes and can convert `gb2312` though.

Comment: mb_convert_encoding supports CP949 under the name UHC according to http://php.net/manual/en/mbstring.supported-encodings.php

Comment: @borrible funny thing is that the docs say `UHC (CP949)` but they couldn't bother to alias it to CP949 as well :P

Answer (score 2):

According to the [list of supported character encodings](http://php.net/manual/en/mbstring.supported-encodings.php) there are only a small number of encodings listed explicitly by code page.  Given the small number of these cases - whilst not a built-in normalisation as requested - a list of mappings may not be too inappropriate.

The relevant ones appear to be the following (the lowercase name on the right is the name you'll need to convert from):

- CP932 shift_jis
- CP51932 euc_jp
- CP50220 iso-2022-jp
- CP50221 csISO220JP
- CP50222 iso-2022-jp
- CP936 gb2312
- CP950 big5

The following are also listed by code-page on the PHP documentation but appear to have suitable synonyms already:

- CP866 (IBM866)
- UHC (CP949)
- Windows-1251 (CP1251)
- Windows-1252 (CP1252)